# Installed package, lsleases, giving bash "No such file or directory" error

Tags: bash

I am trying to use, the following package, lsleases:

https://github.com/j-keck/lsleases#usage

I have tried installing using the deb package and also via the bintray.com repository, as detailed in the installation instructions with the same result.

In both cases the installation completes without a problem as far as I can tell.

However, when I try and run the command I get the following error:

```
andrew@T61:~$ lsleases
bash: /usr/bin/lsleases: No such file or directory
andrew@T61:~$ /usr/bin/lsleases
bash: /usr/bin/lsleases: No such file or directory
```

As you can see the file does exist:

```
andrew@T61:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/lsleases 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3386272 Mar 28 16:05 /usr/bin/lsleases
```

Here's the output from which, type, echo $PATH and file if that is helpful:

```
andrew@T61:~$ which lsleases
/usr/bin/lsleases
andrew@T61:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/game:/usr/local/games
andrew@T61:~$ type lsleases
lsleases is hashed (/usr/bin/lsleases)
andrew@T61:~$ file lsleases
lsleases: cannot open `lsleases' (No such file or directory)
```

Here's the output of ldd /usr/bin/lsleases:

```
andrew@T61:~$ ldd /usr/bin/lsleases
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe7a920000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc1241f4000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc123e2a000)
/nix/store/pv9sza1cf2kpawck7wbwdnhlip5h57lg-glibc-2.23/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005589d3780000)
```

Any advice to help me get this working would be great, it looks like a handy tool.

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `file /usr/bin/lsleases`.

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /usr/bin/lsleases`? The behaviour you're describing may be the result of a missing library dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of `lsleases` (that's me) uses [nix](http://nixos.org/nix/) for his development env.

Dynamic linked binaries consults the dynamic linker/loader to provide the shared libs. This path is fixed at compile-time in the binary:

```
 root@debian8:~# readelf -l /usr/bin/lsleases  | grep interpreter
  [Requesting program interpreter: /nix/store/pv9sza1cf2kpawck7wbwdnhlip5h57lg-glibc-2.23/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

But this path only exists under `nix`.

---

The go compiler creates statically-linked binaries by default (if cgo isn't used) - so this is no problem. BUT - I'm currently not sure why, the go compiler created a dynamic linked binary.

I have released a new version (1.4.3) which is statically linked.

So a simple solution (if you have the bintray repo configured):

```
apt-get update && apt-get install lsleases
```

The actual packages can you found [here](https://github.com/j-keck/lsleases/releases/latest).

Sorry for the breakage!